# Amazon MWS API 503 from Cloud Function, 200 from Local

Tags: google-cloud-functions, amazon-mws

I've got an amazon MWS api call to get orders.

When I run locally, it's fine and returns the results.

However, when I run it from google cloud, it returns;
HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable

There have been cases when I do get results, but it's not lining up with their quotas.

I tried to do exponential backoff as stated, but getting the same error.

Even if GCP gives 503, local always returns 200.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my issue. Was incorrectly looping over next page token.